# When should I use Scala's `package` special identifier?

Tags: scala, package

In Scala, you can define [package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html). It seems thus that you can access that package object by writing the package name, and then `` `package` ``:

```
// file package.scala in src/com

package com
package object test {
  val Version = 2
}

// file Test.scala in src/test

package test
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = com.test.`package`          // get ref on package object
    val v1 = com.test.`package`.Version // (1) get val
    val v2 = com.test.Version           // (2) get val
  }
}
```

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? In some cases, I've had to write the extra `` `package` `` for my code to run. Should there be a difference or is it a compiler bug?

Moreover, what does e.g. this line mean, in `Predef.scala`?

```
scala.`package`   // to force scala package object to be seen.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a blind guess: The line

```
scala.`package`
```

results in a simple `getstatic` (the package object code) followed by `pop`. So it is doing nothing more but initialising the package object if it wasn’t already initialised before.

So my guess is that in `Predef.scala` you cannot be sure (or it may be definite that it has not happened) that the package object has been initialised already. Most other modules may *implicitly* depend on `Predef` being loaded, so these modules cannot just be initialised blindly. Therefore one needs to ensure this by including the module/package/object explicitly in `Predef`. Same is done for the List module and StringBuilder. So, it might just be an initialisation order thing.

Comment: Hey, I checked, and your blind guess seems to be correct. It is indeed compiled into a `getstatic` followed by `pop`. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between (1) and (2) in your code.
The package object allows you to write it as (2). But you may still write is as (1).

I can only imagine that the cases in which you had to write `package` in your code must have to do something with your development environment (Eclipse/Scala plugin?) expecting a class named "package" to stem from a source named "package.scala" and not from "test.scala".
Can you reproduce the cases in which you *had* to write `package`?

I am also curious what the effect of that line is in Predef.

Comment: On one instance here, if I don't write “`package`” I get a `java.lang.VerifyError: ... Expecting to find object/array on stack`, so I assume it's definitely a compiler problem. For some reason I cannot reproduce it on a minimal example…

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have asked two questions in one, as now I'd need to accept both your and Debilski's answer… Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, package objects (introduced in Scala 2.8) mean that anything declared within them is automatically within scope of other code in the same package. So the package object in `Predef.scala` contains things imported into the top level Scala scope. Martin Odersky, the creator of Scala, wrote a [good introduction to them](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/package_objects.html) on Artima a year ago.

Comment: Thanks. I know what package objects are; I was curious about the difference between (1) and (2) in my code, and what the effect of that line in Predef is.

Comment: Ok, I see. Luckily you got some better responses!

Answer (score 1):

The word `package` is a reserved keyword in Scala. However, it is the name (identifier) of package objects. So if you need to access directly the package object, you need to use the backquotes to "escape" the word package.

The following definition is equivalent to the one you posted in your question:

```
// file package.scala in src/com
package com.test
object `package` {
  val Version = 2
}
```

Moreover, the line in Predef.scala

```
scala.`package`   // to force scala package object to be seen.
```

allows you to directly access the package object as any other object.

Comment: Thanks. But I actually wanted to know the difference between (1) and (2) in my code, and what the effect of that line in Predef is. What would happen if it was not there?